# Trace Routing for a Certain port

Tags: networking, port, icmp, windows-firewall, traceroute

Before saying anything let me tell you that i am not well educated int networks related subjects.

I am a software developer and I have written and exposed a Service on HTTPS at port 8000. Now i want to know that if there is any kind of software that can help me to trace if there is any kind of port blocking from one site to my service location with information of blocker host.

I have tried couple of Tracerout software like wintrace but all these uses ICMP protocols and there is no option to provide port number in them.

And moreover i like to ad an exception in Firewall for incoming ICMP protocal in windows server 2003 windows firewall but i can't see anyoption to ad protocol in exception instead there are only options to ad a program or ad a port of udp or tcp.

Please help
Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NMAP, my good friend will do this for you :)

The classic example is from the [NMAP manual](https://nmap.org/book/man.html) and manpage such as the [Debian manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nmap/nmap.1.en.html) follows:

`nmap -A -T4 scanme.nmap.org`

"The only Nmap arguments used in this example are `-A`, to enable OS and version detection, script scanning, and traceroute; `-T4` for faster execution; and then the hostname."

If you want even more control you can use `nping` in the NMAP suite, the example in [NMAP manual](https://nmap.org/book/man.html) (Chapter 5) follows:

`nping --udp --traceroute -c 13 -p 53 scanme.nmap.org`

Comment: WOW thats wonderful thing, Thanks a Lot, Thanks to nmap team as well. 

What about send little question???

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: "send little question", could you please explain. With respect to the firewall configuration, this might be better asked on serverfault.com.

Comment: sorry actually it was "What about my second(2nd) question?" i.e how to add icmp in firewall exception in wind 2k3 server

Comment: Could be nice to have an example on a certain port with NMAP... not having to dig into the man pages. For ex see where the ssh port 22 is blocked (ISP/etc)

Comment: Thanks, @Pipo, you're right in the 10 years the page changed :P. I put the example from the page directly into the answer and added another from later in the book. :)

Answer (score 0):

TTL is enforced regardless of protocol.